# My answer is not the same as the one on the question

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Question

As part of 25 years Birthday celebration, Any order that is between R1000 and R3000 receives a 2% discount on their total amount. Declare a parameterized cursor that receives minimum and maximum amount as parameters and update the total amount by locking the transaction. Iterate through the whole result set and decreasing total by 2%.
Your output must resemble the one below.

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> /
ORDERS THAT ARE BETWEEN R1000 AND R3000.00, RECEIVE 2% DISCOUNT
-------------------------------------------------------------------
ORDER NO. 105  HAVE A TOTAL AMOUNT OF:             R2,314.13
ORDER NO. 105 HAVE A NEW TOTAL ANOUNT OF :            R2,267.85
ORDER NO. 110  HAVE A TOTAL AMOUNT OF:             R1,308.38
ORDER NO. 110 HAVE A NEW TOTAL ANOUNT OF :            R1,282.21
ORDER NO. 111  HAVE A TOTAL AMOUNT OF:             R2,354.71
ORDER NO. 111 HAVE A NEW TOTAL ANOUNT OF :            R2,307.62

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Below is my code:

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE

CURSOR ord_cur(p_min NUMBER,p_max NUMBER) IS
    SELECT id,total
    FROM s_ord
    WHERE total BETWEEN p_min AND p_max
    FOR UPDATE OF total NOWAIT;
    ord_rec ord_cur%ROWTYPE;

        BEGIN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ORDERS THAT ARE BETWEEN R1000 AND R3000.00,RECEIVE 2% DISCOUNT');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('********************************************');
        OPEN ord_cur(1000,3000);
    LOOP
        FETCH ord_cur
        INTO ord_rec;
        EXIT WHEN ord_cur%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ORDER NO '|| ord_rec.id ||' HAVE A TOTAL AMOUNT OF: '||TO_CHAR((ord_rec.total),'L9,999.09'));

        IF  ord_rec.total >= 1000 AND ord_rec.Total <= 3000 THEN
            UPDATE s_ord
            SET total = ord_rec.total*0.02
            WHERE CURRENT OF ord_cur;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ORDER NO '|| ord_rec.id ||' HAVE A NEW TOTAL AMOUNT OF: '||TO_CHAR((ord_rec.total),'L9,999.09'));
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Below is my output which is different to the output of the question:

```
ORDERS THAT ARE BETWEEN R1000 AND R3000.00,RECEIVE 2% DISCOUNT
********************************************
ORDER NO 105 HAVE A TOTAL AMOUNT OF:           $2,722.24
ORDER NO 105 HAVE A NEW TOTAL AMOUNT OF:           $2,722.24
ORDER NO 110 HAVE A TOTAL AMOUNT OF:           $1,539.13
ORDER NO 110 HAVE A NEW TOTAL AMOUNT OF:           $1,539.13
ORDER NO 111 HAVE A TOTAL AMOUNT OF:           $2,770.00
ORDER NO 111 HAVE A NEW TOTAL AMOUNT OF:           $2,770.00

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

What have I done wrong?

BELOW IS THE TABLE OF DATA:
SQL> SELECT *
2  FROM   s_ord;

```
    ID CUSTOMER_ID  DATE_ORDERED    DATE_SHIPPED SALES_REP_ID       TOTAL  PAYMENT_TYPE     ORDER_FILLED
```

---

```
   100         204  31/AUG/92   10/SEP/92             11       601100  CREDIT   Y
   101         205  31/AUG/92   15/SEP/92             14       8056.6  CREDIT   Y
   102         206  01/SEP/92   08/SEP/92             15         8335  CREDIT   Y
   103         208  02/SEP/92   22/SEP/92             15          377  CASH     Y
   104         208  03/SEP/92   23/SEP/92             15        32430  CREDIT   Y
   105         209  04/SEP/92   18/SEP/92             11      2722.24  CREDIT   Y
   106         210  07/SEP/92   15/SEP/92             12        15634  CREDIT   Y
   107         211  07/SEP/92   21/SEP/92             15       142171  CREDIT   Y
   108         212  07/SEP/92   10/SEP/92             13       149570  CREDIT   Y
   109         213  08/SEP/92   28/SEP/92             11      1020935  CREDIT   Y
   110         214  09/SEP/92   21/SEP/92             11      1539.13  CASH     Y
   111         204  09/SEP/92   21/SEP/92             11         2770  CASH     Y
    97         201  28/AUG/92   17/SEP/92             12        84000  CREDIT   Y
    98         202  31/AUG/92   10/SEP/92             14          595  CASH     Y
    99         203  31/AUG/92   18/SEP/92             14         7707  CREDIT   Y
   112         210  31/AUG/92   10/SEP/92             12          550  CREDIT   Y
```

16 rows selected.

Comment: Please try to build an example, so that people can check your data, logics and result. As is, how can we know what's wrong, without knowing the data you are working on?

Comment: I guess, the issue is with order number. In the task it is said " order that is between R1000 and R3000", but I can not see this in your code

Comment: This is such a sad question, because a cursor is not needed.  And cursors should not be used when they are not needed.

Comment: @Aleksej i tried to copy the table with data here but it say i exceed character

Comment: @Aleksej I have edited the question as included the data

Comment: @GordonLinoff please check the table of the data from s_ord table

Comment: @Sergey I have added the table with data....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Given that you need a cursor as per your homework instructions, you are not actually too far off. The direct cause of your output problem is that while your update statement changes the value on the database it does not change the value in the cursor. But you used the cursor value in both dbms_output statement. Secondly you do not need the IF statement. Your cursor contains a where clause that squareness your IF statement evaluates every true every time. Finally you have a minor calculation problem. The formula "total = ord_rec.total*0.02" does not give a 2% discount, it gives a 98% discount. Taking all this together you get:
declare

```
    cursor ord_cur(p_min number,p_max number) is
        select id,total
          from s_ord
         where total between p_min and p_max
           for update of total nowait;
           
    ord_rec ord_cur%rowtype;

begin
    dbms_output.put_line('ORDERS THAT ARE BETWEEN R1000 AND R3000.00,RECEIVE 2% DISCOUNT');
    dbms_output.put_line('********************************************');
    open ord_cur(1000,3000);
    
    loop
        fetch ord_cur
         into ord_rec;
        exit when ord_cur%notfound;
        dbms_output.put_line('ORDER NO '|| ord_rec.id ||' HAVE A TOTAL AMOUNT OF: '||to_char(ord_rec.total),'L9,999.09'));
    
        update s_ord
           set total = ord_rec.total*0.98     ---   ord_rec.total - (ord_rec.total*0.02)  
         where current of ord_cur;
    
        dbms_output.put_line('ORDER NO '|| ord_rec.id ||' HAVE A NEW TOTAL AMOUNT OF: '||to_char((ord_rec.total*0.98),'L9,999.09'));

    end loop;
end;
```